# Could Meltdown/Spectre be exploited from C#/.Net (or other managed languages or the Midori OS)?

Tags: .net, meltdown, spectre

First off yes the correct answer is **patch your OS/system**. That aside:

Does the memory managed features of a language like C# prevent it from being used to exploit the Meltdown security bug?

What about if you use the `unsafe` keyword?

Bonus question:
Could Meltdown/Spectre be exploited on the Midori operating system?

Comment: No, managed runtimes (if implemented reasonable efficient with a JIT) do not protect against all variants. Because array bound checks in those languages might expose speculatively other data. The Spectre paper contains a sample JavaScript snippet and it’s V8 compiled code to discuss this. It is most likely CLR and JVM have the same property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could Meltdown be exploited from C#/.Net (or other managed languages)?

It can [even be done from JavaScript](https://react-etc.net/page/meltdown-spectre-javascript-exploit-example).

Comment: it will only be a problem in JS for a few more weeks, but it could take years for "binary" apps to get fixed.

Comment: @dandavis - C# binaries are still interpreted and require a run-time to be present. The run-time environment can be patched independently from the applications - as can the underlying OS. Microsoft can fix .NET via an automated update just as easily as Google can fix chrome (although I imagine more Windows users have disabled automatic updates - and i'd also expect Microsoft to just fix the OS and leave .NET alone). Also unlike with JS it is rare to run entirely untrusted C# code on a machine outside of VM hosts.

Comment: Is that specifically Meltdown?  People are conflating the two somewhat.  I would have thought that you'd need some insight into kernel address layout and the ability to manage the cache.

Comment: @DavidA - you're right in that my link is Spectre related - i'll try to update it in the morning when I have more than a mobile to hand. But both can be exploited easily via JS / most interpreted environments.

Comment: @dandavis All (mostly true). It is possible to use Ahead Of Time (AOT) compilation, i.e.,  JIT compilation (what I think you mean by interpreted) and a runtime is not needed. But if you are using that you really should sort out your deployment/update pipeline first.

Comment: AOT actually makes it easier to exploit has the form of the optimized code is known at the beginning and requires no warmup.